# C Python Extension object type

Tags: c, python-3.x, python-extensions

Is there a way to find out the type of a Python Object in C extension?  I need to pass a name(string) or a double value from script to my extension.  I thought I could call parsetuple in my extension and get the argument into a Python Object(using format string "O"), and check to see what the type is, and use it accordingly, but have not been able to find anything on that.  I did search the site for answers. If you know this has already been answered, please provide a link, asking me to go search again will not be productive.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Python 3.x.

You can use [`PyUnicode_Check()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html?highlight=pyunicode_check#c.PyUnicode_Check) to check if the object is a string, then the `PyUnicode_AsXXX()` functions (documented on the same page) or one of the parse tuple functions.

Similarly with [`PyFloat_Check()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/float.html?highlight=pyfloat_check#c.PyFloat_Check) for floating point numbers.